# is there a way to do onChange() on internent explorer only with Javascript, HTML, CSS (No Jquery)

Tags: javascript, html, css

is there a way to do onChange() on internent explorer only with Javascript, HTML, CSS (No Jquery). My code send the input to my function upon onChange(). It worked perfectly when I was using chrome. But I just notice that onChange() doesn't work on I.E like it does on chrome. Is there a way to make it work like it does on chrome Or is there something else that I could do which would call the function after I select an option? If not I have to change all 400 lines of my script code :(

```
<label>Choose a browser from this list:
        <input id = "input1" list="table1" name="myBrowser" 
        style="width: 500px;"  onchange="castvote('input1','table1')" onclick="test('input1')"/> 
</label>
    <datalist id="table1">
        <option value="Firefox">      
        <option value="more options">
```

Comment: why not use js to add the event listener to the element. then you will get consistent behavior across all browsers.

Comment: I only want to call my function when the user select an option on the dropdown menu. Is there another way to do that? if so can you tell me how I'm still very new

Comment: see my answer below for a very simple example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a very simple example of adding listeners via vanilla js.
Now it has been updated to look for a class such as castVote and in a loop add the listener to each element

```js
(function addCastVoteListeners() {
  const els = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.castVote'));
  els.forEach(addCastVoteListener);
})();
function addCastVoteListener(el) {
  el.addEventListener('change', castVote);
}
function castVote() {
  console.log('cast vote');
}
```

```html
<label>Choose a browser from this list:
        <input id = "input1" list="table1" name="myBrowser" class="castVote"
        style="width: 500px;"/> 
</label>
<datalist id="table1">
    <option value="Firefox">      
    <option value="more options">
</datalist>
```

Comment: Thanks but is there a way to do this wihthout hard coding like this document.getElementById(INSERTVariable).addEventListener('change', castvote);
The reason is that I have about 30 different input being pass. and I don't wan to make 30 lines saying document.getElementById('inputNum').addEventListener('click', test);

Comment: @randomvincent the updated answer should address your desire

Comment: thanks. Sorry for keep on bothering you but one last question. How would I grab the input id from this. and how would I find the value of the input. so in this case input id is "input1" and let's say I selected the firefox option. then the input is firefox

Comment: @randomvincent its time to try searching very elemental questions if you are going to delve very far into vanilla js. here is how you find an elements id https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_id.asp

Comment: that seems unrelated. this code is very basic and should be agnostic. the back and forward caching in your console is more of a warning than anything stemming from this.